# Codename One: image as background of a container, container remains size 0

Tags: codenameone

The overall goal is to have a pic which resizes to fit a portion of the screen, *working all from the designer (no code)*.

I set an image as a a background for a container. Should work except that as long as I don't add a component in the container, the container remains of size 0, so the pic is not showing.

How do I add a pic to the background of a container and set a size for the container?

Comment: tried the ImageViewer instead. The image displays but does not fit the screen size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background image is a styling element and isn't defined as content. Hence, it has no effect on the preferred size of the container which remains 0 thus the container has no size.

You can place the container in the center of a border layout. Border layout's center constraint is a special case (unless absolute center is used) where the component is given available space regardless of its preferred size.

`ImageViewer` should have the image fit the space it occupies, that is its default behavior. Make sure its sized correctly with the layout manager.

Comment: Thanks! So, the form has a border layout. I have created 4 labels that I put at North, South, East, West. The container, which has a pic for background (scale to fit) and is empty (has no component in it), is at the center. The pic appears alright in the GUI builder, but not in the simulator? (I just see the 4 labels, and an empty center)

Comment: How big is the image pixel wise? Does it fail in all the simulators or specific ones? Are you sure you saved the file and didn't change the UIID in any way? Also try changing the opacity of the assigned UIID to 255 to make sure its appearing.

Comment: Ok: does not work in the simulator when the simulator is launched from the designer, but the image displays ok when I do Project -> Run

Comment: Odd. Probably a bug in that feature.